# jOOQ dynamic SQL questions

Tags: mysql, sql, jooq

#### Question 1:

mybatis dynamic-sql as follows：

```xml
<select id="queryList" resultType="io.renren.entity.SysMenuEntity">
        select m.*,(select p.name from sys_menu p where p.menu_id = m.parent_id) as parentName 
            from sys_menu m
        <choose>
            <when test="sidx != null and sidx.trim() != ''">
                order by m.${sidx} ${order}
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                order by m.order_num asc
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <if test="offset != null and limit != null">
            limit #{offset}, #{limit}
        </if>
    </select>
```

How to achieve in jooq?

#### Question 2:

I have the following SQL in jooq how to achieve?

Query the permissions of a user based on table resource_id, sys_role_resource, sys_user_role

```sql
SELECT 
    t4.resource_id,
    t4.name,
    t4.parent_id,
    t4.perms,
    t4.url,
    (SELECT 
            t3.name
        FROM
            sys_resource t3
        WHERE
            t3.resource_id = t4.parent_id) AS parentName
FROM
    sys_resource t4
WHERE
    EXISTS( SELECT 
            t2.resource_id
        FROM
            sys_role_resource t2
        WHERE
            EXISTS( SELECT 
                    t1.role_id
                FROM
                    sys_user_role t1
                WHERE
                    t1.user_id = 1))
ORDER BY t4.order_num ASC;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'll answer both of your questions in one answer, but in the future, ideally, it is better to ask only one question per question.

Comment: Okay, I remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer 1:

Dynamic SQL is very easy with jOOQ. There's an entire section in the jOOQ manual dedicated to it:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql

Essentially, you need to understand that every method that you call on a jOOQ object produces a sort of SQL *expression* (a [`QueryPart`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/QueryPart.html)), which can be assigned to a local variable and used to compose complex, dynamic SQL statements. Or, you don't assign those expressions to local variables and inline them directly. It's up to you.

In your case, I'm assuming you have used the jOOQ [code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/) to generate the `SYS_MENU` table:

```java
// Assuming these imports:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
import static com.example.generated.Tables.*;

// And then...
SysMenu m = SYS_MENU.as("m");
SysMenu p = SYS_MENU.as("p");

DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(m.fields())
   .select(field(select(p.NAME).from(p).where(p.MENU_ID.eq(m.PARENT_ID))).as("parentName"))
   .from(m)
   .orderBy(
        sidx != null && sidx.trim() != ""
      ? m.field(sidx).sort("desc".equals(order) ? SortOrder.DESC : SortOrder.ASC)
      : m.ORDER_NUM.asc())
   .limit(offset != null ? offset : 0, limit != null ? limit : Integer.MAX_VALUE)
   .fetch();
```

#### Answer 2:

This query translates 1:1 to jOOQ

```java
SysUserRole t1 = SysUserRole.as("t1");
SysRoleResource t2 = SysRoleResource.as("t2");
SysResource t3 = SysResource.as("t3");
SysResource t4 = SysResource.as("t4");

DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(
        t4.RESOURCE_ID
        t4.NAME,
        t4.PARENT_ID,
        t4.PERMS,
        t4.URL,
        field(
            select(t3.NAME)
           .from(t3)
           .where(t3.RESOURCE_ID.eq(t4.PARENT_ID))
        )).as("parentName"))
   .from(t4)
   .whereExists(
        select(t2.RESOURCE_ID)
       .from(t2)
       .whereExists(
            select(t1.ROLE_ID)
           .from(t1)
           .where(t1.USER_ID.eq(1))
       )
   )
   .orderBy(t4.ORDER_NUM.asc())
   .fetch();
```

Comment: Answer 1:in jooq “limit(offset, limit)” equivalent to mybatis "<if test="offset != null and limit != null">
            limit #{offset}, #{limit}
        </if>" ?

Comment: @ChunfyTseng: No, I've overlooked that part, sorry. Updated the answer with a possible alternative.